# Why cannot execute php code from html?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, netbeans

I have been fighting with this issue for many days and got really stuck.
I'm trying to call a php script which contains code to access mysql database from a html file through javascript. But when I run the following on my NetBeans, I always get error at "$.ajax({" place. And NetBean doesn't specify what error it is. It only says Request was cancelled. Please help me out!!!!

HTML:

```
<form>
    <p><input type="text" name="username" value=""></p>
    <p><input type="password" name="password" value=""></p>
    <p class="remember_me">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="remember_me">
            Remember me on this computer
        </label>
    </p>
    <p><input type="submit" onClick="connect_to_db()" name="submit" value="Login" id="submit"></p>
    <script>
        function connect_to_db(){
            utils.connectToDb(document.getElementsByName("username")[0].value,
                document.getElementsByName("password")[0].value);
        }
    </script>
</form>
```

api/connect.php:

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb', $username, $password);
    $insert_cmd = "INSERT INTO version VALUES(1)";
    $read_cmd = "SELECT * FROM version";
    foreach($dbh->query($insert_cmd) as $row) {
        print_r($row);
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
?>
```

util.js:

```
window.utils = {
    connectToDb: function (username, password) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'api/connect.php',
            data: {'username': username, 'password': password},
            type: 'post',
            success: function(output) {
                alert(output);
            }
        });
    },    
};
```

NOTE: I have used similar code on Windows, and it worked. I'm currently exporting this to my Mac. I have also enabled php5 module in https.conf and configured my php.ini. I have tested my php and apache using a simple .php file which contains  in it. And it is able to display the php information.

Comment: What is a `foreach` over a `INSERT` statement supposed to do?

Comment: $dbh->query($insert_cmd) returns a list of results. The results will be unpacked one by one and each one will be stored in the variable $row. foreach is a keyword for an iterator to iterate through the unpacked list of results. I just put it there for result display purpose.

Comment: Well, it does *not* return the list of results. There are no results, because its an INSERT statement. You have to query the SELECT statement in order to get some actual rows to iterate over. Your PHP code returns an empty response (which might be a problem) in the case the connection was successful and an error message if it was not.

Comment: oh, I didn't notice that. I thought I put in the read query. And I just removed the reading part completely. Yet it's still the same problem. Any idea?

Comment: Use the developer tools of your favorite browser and check the network traffic for your ajax request. Check the response sent by your server. You might get a response code >= 400 and your success callback is never called.

Comment: I did try that, I used google chrome and the developer console. The weird thing is, I can see the request sent out. But I don't see any response.

Comment: Makes sense, because the response is empty in the case the connection can be established. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: I'm adding a simple login page to a html website I'm working on. I use a mysql database to store my credential. So, I want to be able to enter my username and password on the html page and then use javascript and ajax to call a php code which will interact with my mysql database. That's what I'm trying to achieve, but everytime I receive an error when calling the php code using $.ajax ..... And the error doesn't say what's wrong, it only says Request has been cancelled.

Comment: I expect to see some change in the database, cause i put a small insert command along with the login for a quick test.

Comment: It is really weird. I converted everything into php code, and it works without any problems. But as long as I interact with javascript and html, the problem comes......i'm totally speechless now. Its the same server, same setup. The only difference is the involvement of javascript and php.

Comment: Don't convert it to server code, try to simulate the client. Use a tool like Fiddler and try to make some requests manually. Check the response you get and compare to what you get using Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If it worked before and you didn't changed the code then its probably a setting.

Check if

- Database server running
- Database exists (with the same credentials)
- Differences in the php version can effect this
- AJAX call is to the new server (same domain/host)
- the chmod rights are ok

Comment: Database server is running. Database exists with the same credentials. I haven't checked the php version. AJAX call is to the new server? You mean if the AJAX call is to the correct server? What rights should I change with chmod?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best answer but I'm sure this will work because this is the best way to connect to mysql database:

```
$dblocation="localhost"; //Your db location
$yourusername= "root"; //db name
$yourpass= ""; //blah3x
$dbname = "sample"; //database name

$connect = mysqli_connect($dblocation,$yourusername,$yourpass,$dbname);
```

You can use either `mysql` or `mysqli` but mysqli is much more better.